# Storing wc into a variable saves the complete file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, wc

I am trying to store the output of wc into a variable but have some problems

- first i cannot use

  `COUNT=$(ls -1 file.log | wc -l)`
  because i get the error:

  > Variable Syntax.
- Second if i do something like this

  `COUNT='ls -1 file.log | wc -l'`

then i type`$count` i get something like:the content of the file

> cat: Cannot open |: No such file or directory
>
> cat: Cannot open wc: No such file or directory
>
> cat: Cannot open -l: No such file or directory

Also if i try to use

`COUNT='wc -l < ./file.log'`

if i type $count i get:

> wc: cannot open < 58 ./file.log 58 total

Any help would be greatly appreciated for me.

Comment: Why not just `COUNT=$(wc -l file.log |awk '{print $1}')` ?

Comment: I get the error: Variable syntax.

Comment: What kind of shell are you using? What is the output of `ps` command?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong quote.  You need to be using the backquote (`) (the one to the left of the number 1 in most keyboards)

Try,

```
count=`wc -l file.log`
count=`ls -1 file.log | wc -l`
echo $count
```

Comment: With the first one i get this: 80: Command not found.  with the second one i get 1: syntax error at line 1 : `(' unexpected

Comment: @Ram  can you give the output of the these commands `which wc` and `alias wc`

Comment: And, are you executing these commands in a console or are they part of a shell script?

Comment: the first one returns 
vt220
/usr/bin/wc
the second one don't return anything, also i am typing them in a console

Comment: @Ram can you execute this and then try the above commands? `export TERM=vt100`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the C shell (csh). It should look like this:

```
#!/bin/csh

set count = `wc -l /path/to/file | cut -d' ' -f1`
echo "$count"
```

Look at this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Shell_Scripting/Variables

Alternatively you'd need to run the script with `bash` if it is installed.